# .NET MAUI: problem open Image File from Resources\Images\some_image.png

Tags: android, .net, image, maui, visual-studio-2022

I need to pass a local / project Image as a Base64String to an API. This approach:

```
string imagePath = "Resources/Images/dotnet_bot.png";
byte[] imageBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(imagePath);
string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
return base64String;
```

produces following exception:

> Could not find a part of the path '/Resources/Images/dotnet_bot.png'.

Another approach:

```
using var imageEncodeStream = await FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync("dotnet_bot.png");
using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
{
    imageEncodeStream.CopyTo(memoryStream);
    return Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
}
```

produces

> File not found exception

*Could somebode help me please?*

Comment: Well where did you put your image at design time? There are many places. Dont let us guess. And you should not treat a resource file as a normal file to begin with. So cannot use the File class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already solved the problem, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official document about the [`FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/storage/file-system-helpers?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=android) said:

> FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync

> Files that were added to the project with the Build Action of MauiAsset can be opened with this method. .NET MAUI projects will process any file in the Resources\Raw folder as a MauiAsset.
> The FileSystem.OpenPackageFileAsync method can't get the length of the stream on Android by accessing the Result.Length property. Instead, you have to read the whole stream and count how many bytes there are to get the size of the asset.

And the `Resources/Images/dotnet_bot.png`'s build action is **MauiImage** not `MauiAsset`. So you get the error.

**Update:**

The full code in the csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

      <PropertyGroup>
            <TargetFrameworks>net8.0-android;net8.0-ios;net8.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
            <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
            <!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
            <!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->

            <!-- Note for MacCatalyst:
            The default runtime is maccatalyst-x64, except in Release config, in which case the default is maccatalyst-x64;maccatalyst-arm64.
            When specifying both architectures, use the plural <RuntimeIdentifiers> instead of the singular <RuntimeIdentifier>.
            The Mac App Store will NOT accept apps with ONLY maccatalyst-arm64 indicated;
            either BOTH runtimes must be indicated or ONLY macatalyst-x64. -->
            <!-- For example: <RuntimeIdentifiers>maccatalyst-x64;maccatalyst-arm64</RuntimeIdentifiers> -->

            <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
            <RootNamespace>MauiApp3</RootNamespace>
            <UseMaui>true</UseMaui>
            <SingleProject>true</SingleProject>
            <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
            <Nullable>enable</Nullable>

            <!-- Display name -->
            <ApplicationTitle>MauiApp3</ApplicationTitle>

            <!-- App Identifier -->
            <ApplicationId>com.companyname.mauiapp3</ApplicationId>

            <!-- Versions -->
            <ApplicationDisplayVersion>1.0</ApplicationDisplayVersion>
            <ApplicationVersion>1</ApplicationVersion>

            <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'ios'">11.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
            <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'maccatalyst'">13.1</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
            <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'android'">21.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
            <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
            <TargetPlatformMinVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'windows'">10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>
            <SupportedOSPlatformVersion Condition="$([MSBuild]::GetTargetPlatformIdentifier('$(TargetFramework)')) == 'tizen'">6.5</SupportedOSPlatformVersion>
      </PropertyGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
            <!-- App Icon -->
            <MauiIcon Include="Resources\AppIcon\appicon.svg" ForegroundFile="Resources\AppIcon\appiconfg.svg" Color="#512BD4" />

            <!-- Splash Screen -->
            <MauiSplashScreen Include="Resources\Splash\splash.svg" Color="#512BD4" BaseSize="128,128" />

            <!-- Images -->
            <MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />

            <!-- Custom Fonts -->
            <MauiFont Include="Resources\Fonts\*" />

            <!-- Raw Assets (also remove the "Resources\Raw" prefix) -->
            <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
            <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Images\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />

      </ItemGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
            <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
            <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility" Version="$(MauiVersion)" />
            <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="8.0.0" />
      </ItemGroup>

      <ItemGroup>
        <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.png" Resize="True" BaseSize="300,185" />
      </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And the result image:

[image]

Comment: The image must be an embedded resource as i commented in the code snippet.

Comment: Did you mean change its buid action as Embedded Resource? If so, can you display the image in the xaml? @jan-007

Comment: It's amazing. Glad to know you have resolved it. @jan-007

Comment: @Zhang - Almost after two days, suddenly, without me knowing what the problem was, it actually stopped working. Sorry for the misleading information..

Comment: @Zhang - And now, with the new approach - the images are not displayed any more!

Comment: Did you set the image files' buid action as MauiImage? In my answer, the build action is **still MauiImage** and just add `<MauiAsset Include="Resources\Images\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />` to make the image files can also be used as `MauiAsset`. And I have tested my answer, it worked well. @jan-007

Comment: <MauiAsset Include="Resources\Raw\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />
<MauiAsset Include="Resources\Images\**" LogicalName="%(RecursiveDir)%(Filename)%(Extension)" />

The Image has build action set MauiImage.
 The cal of FileSystem.OpenAppPackageFileAsync(imageName)) results in an exception: 
{System.IO.FileNotFoundException: cover.png


When the build action is MauiAsset then the Image File is found and can be open.

@Liyun Zhang

Comment: I tested it with target .net 8 and it worked. In the .net 7, I got a file not found exception. @jan-007

Comment: Did you add `<ItemGroup> <MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.png"  Resize="True"/></ItemGroup>`? @jan-007

Comment: <!-- Images -->
<MauiImage Include="Resources\Images\*" />
<MauiImage Update="Resources\Images\dotnet_bot.png" Resize="True" BaseSize="300,185" />
Tested with .net 8
When build action is set to MauiImage => file not found exception.

Comment: In the .net 8, set the build action as MauiAsset and add the code I provided. Then it will work. @jan-007

Comment: Does it work now? @jan-007

Comment: It's strange. I show the full code in my csproj file and the result image. You can check it. And the buid action is MauiAsset. @jan-007

Comment: I tested it in my app - did not work. Then I created a new test app and it was working! I compared the settings of both app, but I don't see any difference concerning the settings. But basicaly it works - you have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
string imageName = "MauiAppTestImage.Resources.Images.dotnet_bot.png";

// Get the embedded image as a stream
var stream = typeof(MainPage).Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(imageName);
```